# Where can I download the SharePoint 2010 PowerShell Snap-in?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I just need a download link to the SharePoint 2010 Snap-In for PowerShell 2.0.  All of my searches find instructions on how to use it, but not download it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no seperate download available. It comes as a part of SharePoint 2010 install.

Comment: And unfortunately you have to run scripts from one of the farm servers.

Comment: or you can use PowerShell remoting to connect to one of the farm servers (WFE/APP) and run the SharePoint cmdlets.

Comment: Well, that's not ideal.  It would be nice to have intellisense and other features when working on my desktop.

Comment: Yes, You can do that by using PowerShell remoting and importing the remote session into local session. Check this: http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1151